# $\mathbb{R}^J$ with box topology is completely regular

Tags: general-topology

show that $\mathbb{R}^J$ in box topology is completely regular where $J$ is any set. I know it is completely regular in case uniform topology and box topology is finer than uniform topology. Therefore, there are more closed sets in box topology

Comment: What is $RJ$? Do you mean $R^J$?

Comment: As its author notes at the end, a very minor adaptation of [this proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1387635/12042) that $\Bbb R^\omega$ with the box topology is completely regular will do the job.

Comment: Yes, I mean  $R^J$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that $\mathbb R^\omega$ with the box topology is completely regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36319/how-to-prove-that-mathbb-r-omega-with-the-box-topology-is-completely-regular)